# Verify all radio groups have a value checked using a generic selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Verify all **radio groups** have at least 1 value selected using a generic selector and the .each() function.

All the examples I find require the id or name of the single radio options to be used not the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const radios = {};

$('input[type="radio"]').each((i, e) => {
  let $radio = $(e);
  
  if ($radio.is(':checked')) {
    radios[$radio.attr('name')] = $radio.val();
  }
});

console.log(radios);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="ri1">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="ri1" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="ri1">

<input type="radio" value="1" name="ri2">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="ri2">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="ri2" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I am looking to verify all dynamically created radio groups on a page are answered. it could be 1 group or 15 groups.

Comment: @Mikemcs it works with N groups. Just put it in a function an call it whenever you need those values.